# Using ECDSA384 for JWT signature validation in .NET Core (MacOS compatibility problem)

Tags: openssl, cryptography, asp.net-core-2.2, jwt

I have a public key which I am unsure how to use to validate a JWT token's signature with right now. I have tried using the ideas illustrated [here](https://www.scottbrady91.com/C-Sharp/JWT-Signing-using-ECDSA-in-dotnet-Core) (for verification),  but there is a difference in that I am using 384 (not 256, in the example) and am not sure which bytes in the array I should be skipping and taking into consideration. I have also tried using external libraries which also failed, likely for the same reason. I am not sure how to extract X and Y from the public key byte array that I have. The examples all seem to assume that you know X and Y already:

string token = "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsImN0eSI6InRleHRcL3BsYWluIn0.eyJoZWxsbyI6ICJ3b3JsZCJ9.EVnmDMlz-oi05AQzts-R3aqWvaBlwVZddWkmaaHyMx5Phb2NSLgyI0kccpgjjAyo1S5KCB3LIMPfmxCX_obMKA";

```
byte[] x = { 4, 114, 29, 223, 58, 3, 191, 170, 67, 128, 229, 33, 242, 178, 157, 150, 133, 25, 209, 139, 166, 69, 55, 26, 84, 48, 169, 165, 67, 232, 98, 9 };
byte[] y = { 131, 116, 8, 14, 22, 150, 18, 75, 24, 181, 159, 78, 90, 51, 71, 159, 214, 186, 250, 47, 207, 246, 142, 127, 54, 183, 72, 72, 253, 21, 88, 53 };

var publicKey=EccKey.New(x, y);

string json = Jose.JWT.Decode(token,publicKey);
```

Moreover, when I fake out the byte array to get past the initial exceptions due to X and Y being an incorrect size, etc., I found that I still get an exception 100% of the time.
I traced this issue back to the fact that all of the libraries I'm using are trying to create a CngKey which results in an "Unsupported platform exception" since I am developing on MacOS.

Given the table of information [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/cross-platform-cryptography.md), I see this explanation: 
[image: Here is a link as I am disallowed from adding images..] which makes sense. However, I would like to avoid having to implement my own implementation of these libraries simply to use `ECDsaOpenSsl` and install OpenSSL, and I would ideally like to be able to deploy to Windows environments without checking to see which OS is executing code.

To sum this up, there are 2 issues:

1. I'm not sure how to extract X and Y coords from my public key byte
   array. The first example I linked is from someone who knows that the
   first index of the array is skipped and that the rest of the array
   is split evenly. My array would have an uneven number of digits if I
   did that, so I'm not sure which indices to skip if that even applies
   here.
2. I'd like to be able to have parity when verifying the signature in
   both Mac and Windows without rolling my own library.

Comment: (1) How `x` and `y` can be determined from the key depends on the key format. Can you say something about the format or post the key? (2) CNG and `ECDsaCng` are Windows-only. ECDSa is cross-platform supported using `ECDsa.Create()`, which instantiates the type used by the particular platform (e.g. `ECDsaCng` on Windows). Have you tried this for .Net / macOS, see also [here](https://vcsjones.dev/2016/10/17/crypto-in-dotnet-core/) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1918)?

Comment: @Topaco Those links are informative and helpful - thank you. Here is a temp version of a local key I requested: https://cutt.ly/CruTp2l 
It's base 64 encoded with secp384r1

Comment: The posted public key is specified in X.509 format, [here, section C.3](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf), and can be read most easily with an ASN.1 parser, e.g. [here](https://www.pkisolutions.com/tools/asn1editor/). At the very end the raw public key can be found in uncompressed format `04 | x (48 bytes) | y (48 bytes): 04 | ddd1...3ae7 | f01f...2314`. secp384r1 or NIST P-384 is described [here, section 2.5](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf).

Comment: When I use `GetBytes(pubKey)` with my key, I get a byte array with 160 elements in it. Are you saying that I need to get the range from 64-160 and split those into the X and Y?

Comment: Not quite. The Base64 encoded public key `MHYw...fyMU` has a length of 160 bytes. The key must be Base64 decoded _first_, e.g. [here](https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-hex). After the Base64 decoding the key has a length of 120 bytes, of which the _last_ 2*48+1=97 bytes are the raw public key in the format `04 | x (48 bytes) | y (48 bytes)`. But note, it's much easier if the Base64 encoded public key `MHYw...fyMU` is stored in a text file that is then opened with the ASN.1 editor to read the raw public key, see [here](https://pasteboard.co/IOzBdep.gif).

Comment: You're right. I completely forgot that. Thanks for that last link. I'll try this out.

Answer (score -1):

I will only remark on issue no 1:

In the example which you linked, the public key is in uncompressed format, which is always encoded as:

```
0x04 | X | Y
```

where X and Y are unsigned values represented by exact number of bytes corresponding to curve size (e.g. 32 bytes for 256-bit curve). That's why the example skips the first byte and then splits the remaining bytes evenly to get X and Y.

To help you with your public key, you would have to post this key here. Then we can speculate about its encoding.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, the main issue is Mac incompatibility. That is what the bounty is for. Even with a valid ecckey created, all means seem to produce a platform unsupported exception.